# Twitter Widget not showing correctly in firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter, widget

http://www.myprettyvintage.com is having an issue with the twitter widget in the sidebar.
 It works fine in all browsers except for Firefox. I think its a CSS issue but right now I'm clutching at straws any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, and I narrowed it down to cookies possibly being blocked. I was running an Add-On called 'Disconnect' from https://disconnect.me/ . Once I disabled this addon and restarted the browser! the twitter widget started working again.

So if you're using that addon or any other one to block cookies or prevent you from being tracked by social networking sites, you'll need to disable it if you want to see the twitter widget.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the AddBlocker in Firefox....disable it for your site and reload the site to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a

`div.twtr-doc{margin-top: 37px;}`

to your css file. I had the same thing. took me a week to figure this one out.

Answer (score -1):

Options --> Privacy --> Uncheck "Use Tracking Protection In Private Windows"

Comment: You can't expect every user of the website to disable a privacy feature just to use your site.